# boost rational cast to double

Tags: c++, boost, rational-number

Using the following bit of code compiled against boost 1.62:

```
#include <boost/rational.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto val = boost::rational<int64_t>(499999, 2);
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::rational_cast<double>(val) << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
499999/2
250000
```

I would expect rational_cast to output 249999.5
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that even the literal `249999.5` is getting rounded off to `250000`, which makes no sense to me. This isn't a Boost thing but I can't explain why numbers so small are being represented inexactly.

Comment: Does this assert(val < 250000) works? I'm saying this because possibly your `std::setprecision()` is not good enough for `std::cout`.

Comment: assert(val < 250000) passes. Playing around with setprecision does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: I have to disagree with the dup. The dup is asking how to do rounding without involving floating points. This is asking why there is imprecision occurring at all and, as my earlier comment indicated, this is not actually dependent on Boost at all.

Comment: This works: `std::cout << std::fixed << boost::rational_cast<double>(v) << std::endl;`

Comment: @sehe The "duplicate" you are forwarding to is a different situation than this one. assert(v < 25000) works, meaning is not a rounding problem on the rational number, but instead on the output cast. It was a matter of adding `std::fixed` to `std::cout`.

Comment: @AdvSphere :raises-brow: I've reopened it for you, now, I will re-read later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the default formatting for floating-point input/output: 
`std::cout << std::fixed << boost::rational_cast<double>(v) << std::endl;` add `std::fixed` to it.

Comment: And here's some proof http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f960a5aec80b7a04